# Azure AD extract role claim from acesses token and pass it on to the controller

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I would like to know how do i extract the role claim from Azure ID accesses token ?
Ideally i would like to get the role claim in a string Variable in ASP.net Core 3.1 controller and then pass this on to my service layer which will do some kind of call to the backend db.

Any sample code would be of great help to me.

Comment: Is that you want to implement Azure AD auth based on app role? If so, please refer to https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps

Comment: Hi Jim Why don't you make this as an answer instead of a comment so i can give you points and this becomes searchable for other users too :)

Comment: I have post my answer. If it is useful for you, could you please accept it? It can help more people as you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement Azure AD auth based on app role, please refer to the following steps:

1. Define your Application Roles

   a. In the blade for your application in Azure Portal, click **Manifest**.

   b. Edit the manifest by locating the appRoles setting and adding your Application Roles. The role definitions are like the following json.

   ```
   "appRoles": [
    {
        "allowedMemberTypes": [
            "User"
        ],
        "description": "User readers can read basic profiles of all users in the directory",
        "displayName": "UserReaders",
        "id": "a816142a-2e8e-46c4-9997-f984faccb625",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "lang": null,
        "origin": "Application",
        "value": "UserReaders"
    },
    {
        "allowedMemberTypes": [
            "User"
        ],
        "description": "Directory viewers can view objects in the whole directory.",
        "displayName": "DirectoryViewers",
        "id": "72ff9f52-8011-49e0-a4f4-cc1bb26206fa",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "lang": null,
        "origin": "Application",
        "value": "DirectoryViewers"
    }
   ],
   ```

   c. Save the manifest.
2. assign app role to user or groups 
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

Besides, please note that if you want to assign app role to group, you need to have Azure AD Premium license.

3. Code

   a. Configure application to get role claim
    please add following code in startup.cs

   ```
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
      {

            // This flag ensures that the ClaimsIdentity claims collection will be built from the claims in the token
          JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;
       // The following lines code instruct the asp.net core middleware to use the data in the "roles" claim in the Authorize attribute and User.IsInrole()
   services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
          {
              // The claim in the Jwt token where App roles are available.
              options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
          });

     }
   ```

   b. get role claim
         
           `[Authorize(Roles = <your role>")] // In controllers
   // or
   User.IsInRole("<your role>"); // In methods`

   For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps) and  the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles)